# How to resolve "Please provide either 'type' or 'entity' attribute in EntityName.id" error when creating migration in MikroORM?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, mikro-orm

I've been following Ben Awad Fullstack tutorial and have run into an issue. So, I have installed MikroORM and am using PostgreSQL database. The problem is that `npx mikro-orm migration:create` command returns the following error:

```
Error: Please provide either 'type' or 'entity' attribute in Post.id
    at ReflectMetadataProvider.initPropertyType (F:\Web Development\RedditClone\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\ReflectMetadataProvider.js:14:19)
    at F:\Web Development\RedditClone\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\ReflectMetadataProvider.js:9:54
    at ReflectMetadataProvider.initProperties (F:\Web Development\RedditClone\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataProvider.js:26:23)
    at ReflectMetadataProvider.loadEntityMetadata (F:\Web Development\RedditClone\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\ReflectMetadataProvider.js:9:20)
    at MetadataDiscovery.discoverEntity (F:\Web Development\RedditClone\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataDiscovery.js:182:41)
    at MetadataDiscovery.discoverReferences (F:\Web Development\RedditClone\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataDiscovery.js:131:24)
    at MetadataDiscovery.findEntities (F:\Web Development\RedditClone\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataDiscovery.js:71:20)
    at MetadataDiscovery.discover (F:\Web Development\RedditClone\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataDiscovery.js:34:9)
    at Function.init (F:\Web Development\RedditClone\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\MikroORM.js:40:24)
```

I have created Post entity that looks like this:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryKey, Property } from "@mikro-orm/core";

@Entity()
export class Post {
    @PrimaryKey({ type: "number" })
    id!: number;

    @Property()
    createdAt = new Date();

    @Property({ onUpdate: () => new Date() })
    updatedAt = new Date();

    @Property()
    title!: string;
}
```

I have also created config file for MikroORM like so:

```
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import path from "path";

export default {
    migrations: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./migrations"),
        pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.[tj]s$/,
    },
    entities: [Post],
    dbName: "redditclone",
    type: "postgresql",
    debug: !__prod__,
    user: "postgres",
    password: "postgres",
} as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0];
```

It's all being put together in the index.ts script:

```
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import microConfig from "./mikro-orm.config";

const main = async () => {
    const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig);

    const post = orm.em.create(Post, { title: "my first post" });
    await orm.em.persistAndFlush(post);
};

main();
```

I've tried changing the Post entity id to uuid and adding the corresponding object parameter to the @PrimaryKey decorator but the error stays the same.
At the moment I am only using MikroORM and ts-node dependecies.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually fixed it. It looks like the typescript didn't compile correctly so I deleted Post.js file from the src folder and when I compiled it again it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was missing `metadataProvider` in ORM's config file:

```
// orm.config.ts

import { MikroORM } from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { TsMorphMetadataProvider } from '@mikro-orm/reflection';

export default {
    // ...
    metadataProvider: TsMorphMetadataProvider
    // ...
} as Parameters <typeof MikroORM.init> [0];
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me - put type attribute to each column.

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryKey, Property } from '@mikro-orm/core'

@Entity()
export class Post {
  @PrimaryKey({ type: 'number' })
  id!: number

  @Property({ type: 'date' })
  createdAt: Date = new Date()

  @Property({ type: 'date', onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt: Date = new Date()

  @Property({ type: 'text' })
  title!: string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line to your index script (to the top):

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

(and add it to your dependencies if you don't have it there already)

Comment: I've just tried that but the same error is still there unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when running my project with [`tsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx) in development. I switched back to [`ts-node-dev`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev) and the error went away. Compiling it to JavaScript with [`tsc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) would work just fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` to the `tsconfig.json` in my project. I'm no Typescript expert, but it makes sense to me since the default reflection-based metadata provider needs type metadata to work off that presumably wouldn't be there without this option.